# Replace multiple urls in a string (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

This string:
"`https://stackoverflow.com/1 test https://stackoverflow.com/2`" should be converted to: 
"`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/1> stackoverflow.com/1 </a> test <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/2"> stackoverflow.com/2 </a>`"

So what there needs to be changed:

1. Put `<a href>..</a>` around the links so that you can click on it.
2. "https://" or "http://" should be removed inside the a-tag to get a nicer url.

What I have so far:

```
AngularJS

$scope.convertedBio = function(value) {
  var text = value.replace(/(http[^\s]+)/, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
   return text;
}
```

However, this returns "`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/1">https://stackoverflow.com/1</a> test https://stackoverflow.com/2`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function replaceUrls(value) {
  var text = value.replace(/(https?:\/\/)(www\.)?([\S]*)/g, '<a href="$1$2$3">$3</a>');
  return text;
}

var x = replaceUrls('http://stackoverflow.com/1 test https://www.stackoverflow.com/2')

console.log(x)

// output <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/1">stackoverflow.com/1</a> test <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/2">stackoverflow.com/2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Capture the entire URL except the protocol part and optional `www.` into an additional group
2. Use this group's value as the `<a>`'s text
3. Add global modifier

```
var text = value.replace(/(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\s]+))/g, '<a href="$1">$2</a>');
                                                ^      ^  ^                 ^
                                                1      1  3                 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to remove the "https:// www." in the link between the a-tag?